# What's the shortcut for toggling "Color Blended Layers" in Xcode Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I've found that the shortcut for toggling 'Slow Animations' can be done by pressing Shift three times. (I don't know why it's not listed)

I was wondering if anyone knew if there's a toggling shortcut for 'Color Blended Layers' option for iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom system-wide shortcut for this:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to "Keyboard"
3. Select the "Keyboard Shortcuts" area
4. Select the "Application Shortcuts" section
5. Click the "+" to add a new shortcut
6. Enter the name as "Color Blended Layers" (the name **is** case-sensitive)
7. Select a key chord to toggle the behavior (I use Ctrl+Shift+L)

It should start working immediately; no need to restart Xcode or the Simulator. If it was correctly configured, your selected key combination will now appear in the Simulator Debug menu next to the "Color Blended Layers" menu item.

Comment: Holy cow! I can't believe I never knew such a thing. This is mind-boggling. Thanks! I used the same key chord in your honor.